# Is it possble to combine number of float values into one float value and extract the values when needed?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Am working on an algorithm for an iPhone app, where the data i need to keep in memory is exceeding the limit, so is it possible to represent number of float numbers as one float value and retrieve those value when i need.

For instance:

```
float array[4];
array[0]=0.12324;
array[1]=0.56732;
array[2]=0.86555;
array[3]=0.34545;

float combinedvalue=?
```

Comment: I doubt 4 floats are causing the problem.

Comment: it is hard to do that, and if you tried to encode it in a special way, you will proly lose some precision. tell more about the problem and why you need so much memory and perhaps someone knows of a better way to do it.

Comment: floats aren't your problem.  You need to have tens of millions of them in memory before you start to see an issue, at which point the problem isn't the floats themselves but rather the algorithmic choices that cause you to keep so many of them alive.

Answer (score 3):

Not in general, no.  You can't store *4N* bits of information in only *N* bits.

If there's some patten in your numbers, then you might find a scheme.  For example, if all your numbers are of similar value, you could potentially store only the differences between the numbers in lower precision.

However, this kind of thing is difficult, and limited.

Answer (score 2):

If those numbers are exactly 5 digits each, you can treat them as ints by multiplying with 100000. Then you'll need 17 bits for each number, 68 bits in total, which (with some bit-shifting) takes up 9 bytes. Does that help, 9 bytes instead of 16?

Please note that the implementation of your algorithm will also take up memory!

Answer (score 0):

What you are requiring could be accomplished in several different ways.

For instance, in c++ you generally have single precision floats (4 bytes) as the smallest precision available, though I wouldn't be surprised if there are other packages that handle smaller precision floating point values.
Therefore, if you are using double precision floating point values and can get by with less precision then you can switch to a smaller precision.

Now, depending on your range of values you want to store, you might be able to use a fixed-point representation as well, but you will need to be familiar with the nuances of bit shifting and masking, etc.  But, another added benefit of this approach is that it could make your program run faster since fixed-point (integer) arithmetic is much faster than floating-point arithmetic.

The choice of options depends on your data you need to store and how comfortable you are with lower level binary arithmetic.