# Combining 3 floats?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm working with huge 3D models and I need to write them to a file for later use. I have limited disc space, so I need to find a way to save space.

For each vertex in the model I'd like to somehow "combine" the X, Y and Z values (floats) and then be able to decipher them when loading the data.

The floats will only have a max of 3 digit precision (i.e. 3.456).

At first I had the idea of getting the average if the 3 floats, and then have another value that I can somehow extract the X and Y values from, which then I can get the Z value from the average. But after trying this I couldn't get it to work properly.

My goal is to be able to somehow combine the 3 floats into one single integer, but I don't think that's feasible.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about this?

Thanks! ;)

Comment: Will they have some kind of maximum, e.g. always less than 10?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224893/is-it-possble-to-combine-number-of-float-values-into-one-float-value-and-extract although the language is different.

Comment: @minitech No, it's all dependent on the 3D model sadly

Comment: If it has no special maximum how you want put them in one integer?

Comment: Disk space costs less than a dollar for a billion bytes; just how many bytes do you need to write?

Comment: There are compression techniques for 3D models, you could look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Or in bits: 10.xyz, regardless of binary representation already takes at least 13 bits; 3*13 is 39 which can't fit in 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers really have 3 digit precision (e.g. 3.45), and all have values between 0 and 9.99, then you can easily fit them in a single 32-bit integer:

```
int value =
  (int)Math.Round(x * 100.0) * 1000000 +
  (int)Math.Round(y * 100.0) * 1000 +
  (int)Math.Round(z * 100.0);
```

If the numbers have 4 digit precision (e.g. 3.456), then you need a few more bits, i.e. at least 40. If the values can be larger than 9.99 you need another six bits to describe where the decimal separator should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

Using a compression library like zlib is usually more efficient than trying to be clever in saving bits. (In fact, being clever can hurt you if you later decide to use zlib after all.)

If you knew the precision you need, and all 3 numbers are on the same scale, you can store one exponent and 3 mantissas. But I'd try zlib first before going with such an approach.

I'll add that, zlib or not, it'll be helpful to store each number as an offset from some nearby anchor point. Many 3D model formats already do that by having a hierarchy of relatively positioned objects. That way the offset can be smaller, so fewer bits are necessary for the same absolute precision.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well the CLR would handle it, but in Ada you can define fixed-point numeric types, and specify the size that it should occupy.

```
type MY_FIXED is delta 0.001  range -4.0..12.0; -- Or whatever your valid range.
For MY_FIXED'Size use SIZE_IN_BITS;
```

You can get a .NET Ada compiler here: http://libre.adacore.com/libre/download2

(Make sure the windows-dotnet) is the one you get... I've not done it, but I hear that you can integrate it into Visual Studio.